# Share content between 2 controls

Tags: wpf

I have the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainContent" Grid.Column="0">
        Some content
    </ContentControl>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=MainContent, Path=Content}" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

This shows the content of the first ContentControl in both sides.
If I change the "Some content" text to any control it shows the content only in the second ContentControl and not in both.
In my case I need to put there a web browser that will show the same content at a level that if you are watching a movie in one and press pause, it will pause on both.

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot have the same control in two different places. In can be in only one place in the visual tree.

Comment: Why not use a DataTemplate that contains your WebBrowser Control and bind all stuff from there to a central ViewModel. This way you have two created WebBrowser Control but with the same Interaction Logic, e.g. Pause is reflected in both controls.

Comment: As the previous comment mentioned use `DataTemplate`'s if you want both control's to end up having the same visual tree or based on your requirement's you could get away with using a `VisualBrush` to render the 2nd control based on first.